# How to add RemoteRepository in Aether to get Direct Dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, aether

I am using following code to add Remote Repository to get dependencies from an artifact using aether.

```
    public static void main( String[] args )
            throws Exception
        {
            RepositorySystem system = Booter.newRepositorySystem();
            Artifact artifact = new DefaultArtifact( "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.1" );
            List<RemoteRepository> repositories = new ArrayList<RemoteRepository>();


        repositories.add((new RemoteRepository.Builder("central", "", "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2")).build());


        DefaultRepositorySystemSession session = Booter.newRepositorySystemSession(system);

        ArtifactDescriptorRequest descriptorRequest = new ArtifactDescriptorRequest();
        descriptorRequest.setArtifact( artifact );
        descriptorRequest.setRepositories( system.newResolutionRepositories(session, repositories ) );

        ArtifactDescriptorResult descriptorResult = system.readArtifactDescriptor( session, descriptorRequest );

        for ( Dependency dependency : descriptorResult.getDependencies() )
        {
            System.out.println( dependency );
        }
    }
```

but it prompts following error message when tries to read artifact descriptor.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.1
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:329)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:287)
    at org.eclipse.aether.examples.GetDirectDependencies.main(GetDirectDependencies.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:pom:2.1 from/to central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Cannot access https://repo1.maven.org/maven2 with type  using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:314)
```

Comment: Can you try using "default" as repository type? (_new RemoteRepository.Builder("central", "default", "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2")_

Comment: What is meant by default? I can't find any documentation regarding any of the available types.

Comment: @gambo agree that documentation is not useful with a lot of broken links.
As 'Maven2' repository is used, Aether provides layout factory for it and it must be with 'default' content type. See org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.Maven2RepositoryLayoutFactory#Line62